# Forest package: How to use \forestset in the preamble?

Tags: forest, trees, preamble

I'm trying to automate the layout for certain trees that I wish to use repetitively, but I don't seem to be able to get the `\forestset` command to work in the preamble. In the codes below, I suppose that the commented-out portion of the file in the main document, should be unnecessary, once this information has been passed on to the preamble. But as it currently stands, the preamble information fails to amend the default layout of the resulting tree. (Note that this doesn't produce a compilation error, either.)

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,pdftex,dvipsnames,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{ 
  sn edges/.style={
  for tree={
    grow'=0, 
    l=0pt, inner sep=0.075cm, s sep=0.1mm,
    child anchor=west,parent anchor=south,
    anchor=west,calign=first,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node{} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=15pt},
  }
 }
}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  % for tree={
  %   grow'=0, 
  %   l=0pt, inner sep=0.075cm, s sep=0.1mm,
  %   child anchor=west,parent anchor=south,
  %   anchor=west,calign=first,
  %   edge path={
  %     \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
  %     (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node{} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  %   },
  %   before typesetting nodes={
  %     if n=1
  %       {insert before={[,phantom]}}
  %       {}
  %   },
  %   fit=band,
  %   before computing xy={l=15pt},
  % }
[$B$
  [$B_{1}$]
  [$B_{2}$
    [$A$
      [$A_{1}$,tikz={\node [draw,inner sep=0.5pt,fit to=tree]{};}]
      [$A_{2}$
        [$D$]
        [$E$]
      ]
      [$A_{3}$
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You define the style `sn edges` in the preamble, but you don't say that you want your tree to use it. To do this you should provide the style name as a key in your tree.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{ 
  sn edges/.style={
  for tree={
    grow'=0, 
    l=0pt, inner sep=0.075cm, s sep=0.1mm,
    child anchor=west,parent anchor=south,
    anchor=west,calign=first,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node{} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=15pt},
  }
 }
}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
sn edges,
[$B$
  [$B_{1}$]
  [$B_{2}$
    [$A$
      [$A_{1}$,tikz={\node [draw,inner sep=0.5pt,fit to=tree]{};}]
      [$A_{2}$
        [$D$]
        [$E$]
      ]
      [$A_{3}$
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

An alternative is not to create a new style but to apply the given style automatically to all trees using the key `default preamble` in `\forestset`. In this case you don't need to provide a style key to individual trees.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{ 
  default preamble={
  for tree={
    grow'=0, 
    l=0pt, inner sep=0.075cm, s sep=0.1mm,
    child anchor=west,parent anchor=south,
    anchor=west,calign=first,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node{} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=15pt},
  }
 }
}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[$B$
  [$B_{1}$]
  [$B_{2}$
    [$A$
      [$A_{1}$,tikz={\node [draw,inner sep=0.5pt,fit to=tree]{};}]
      [$A_{2}$
        [$D$]
        [$E$]
      ]
      [$A_{3}$
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `\forestset` you need to define style which name is considered in `forest` environment. See MWE below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{my tree/.style = {% NEW
    for tree={
        inner sep=0.075cm, 
        l sep=1mm,% CHANGED AND CORRECTED
        s sep=1mm,% changed
        grow'=0,
        child anchor=west,parent anchor=south,
        anchor=west,calign=first,
        edge path={
          \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
          (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node{} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
        before typesetting nodes={
          if n=1
            {insert before={[,phantom]}}
            {}
        },
        fit=band,
        before computing xy={l=15pt},
            }% end of for tree
                        }% end of my tree style
        }% end of forestset
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} my tree
 [$B$
  [$B_{1}$]
  [$B_{2}$
    [$A$
      [$A_{1}$,tikz={\node [draw,inner sep=0.5pt,fit to=tree]{};}]
      [$A_{2}$
        [$D$]
        [$E$]
      ]
      [$A_{3}$
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You beat me by 20 seconds :D

Comment: @Marijn, than I lucky today! Usual I'm to late :-(.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Marijn and @Zarko, for your speedy answers. It is indeed very handy to use. I'm just somewhat surprised by this unusual syntax, ```\begin{forest} my tree```. I've never come across such a way to pass information to an environment in LaTeX. I thought that this was generally enclosed by squared brackets.

Comment: @Nicomachus Since the core syntax of `forest` uses square brackets to define the tree, it wouldn't helpful to have environment options set using them.